# Accessing global(javascript) variables in a private function

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick, global

I'm currently working on a calculator for learning purposes and everything works, in a way, but not in the way I'd want it to.

Here's the adding up part of the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="int1" />
<input type="number" id="int2" />
<input type="button" onClick="sumOf();" />
<div id="result"></div>  // To display the result
```

JS:

```
var int1 = document.getElementById("int1").value;
var int1 = document.getElementById("int2").value;
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function sumOf(int1, int2) {
  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2);
}
```

The way it is right now, if I call the function via the onClick event it will result in NaN. Checking the type of the int's results in 'undefined'. So I put the variables inside the function and it works fine because now the function can reach them.

My question is how can I give access to the variables outside of the function? I tried creating an object, but then I had problems referring to the right function inside the object in the onClick event, I tried "objectName.functionInsideTheObject();". The result was it didn't work.

How can I make this work? New functions will be added for other calculations and it's tedious to copy paste the variables all the time.

**EDIT:**

My problem has something to do with ".value" in the variable declaration. If I declare a variable as such:

```
var int1 = document.getElementById("int1");  // Not getting the value directly
var int2 = document.getElementById("int2");
```

And then reference to the value of the variable inside the function like this:

```
function sumOf() {
  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(int1.value) + parseFloat(int2.value);
}
```

It works fine. I don't know why .value doesn't work in global scope. Still not perfect, but less tedious.

Comment: the Variables are declared in Global scrope, before you enter any value in the input field.

Comment: So, as I understand it, the page loads, the fields don't have a value(thus why int1 and int2 = NaN) and there is no event updating the variables in case it acquires a value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you create it like this:

```
int1 = document.getElementById("int1").value;
```

without the var it's then a global.

Comment: Since the variables are outside the function, they're global even with `var`. His problem is that he's shadowing the global variables with function arguments.

Comment: That's true, but he declared them as local in a global scope, so they are still global.

Comment: The result is NaN either way. With arguments and without.

Answer (score 1):

The way you declared the variables is Right.

And these variables are NaN as you are agaian padding them as Arguments in your function

```
function sumOf(int1, int2) {
  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2);
}
```

you should call the function like

```
function sumOf() {
  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2);
}
```

But I think will be better if you declare your function like

```
function sumOf() {
  var int1 = document.getElementById("int1").value;
  var int1 = document.getElementById("int2").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  result.innerHTML = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2);
}
```